# How to update JSF web application components without broking it's current functionality?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, richfaces, upgrade, icefaces

I have a large web application (100+ jsf pages) using **RichFaces 4.1.0**. I was trying new features offered by **RichFaces 4.3.0** (**rich:placeHolder**, for example). This brings me to the question: If I really want to use the new RichFaces version, how can I know if it's safe to upgrade?

I think that it is very unsafe because of different factors: old bugs, new bugs, changes in functionalities, code already written (that is not necessarily good...), ...

However, I would like to know, how do you normally approach this kind of problems in a production project. Is it avoidable by constructing a very "*good*" test set by using **JUnit**, **Mockito**, **Arquillian** or any other? Or maybe **letting the application as it is would be the best approach once it has been delivered**? In this case, we will never upgrade any jar in it, (*avoid a much as possible*)?

In this specific problem, RichFaces team has developed an internal framework called [CDK](http://www.bleathem.ca/blog/2011/11/richfaces-4-cdk-jqeury-ui-tabs.html) which provides components independence in order to facilitate modularization. This means that we can take **rich:placeHolder** component and create a single *jar* for it. Then we will have to add this new *jar* to our application. This avoid upgrading all the main richfaces *jar*. This should work fine in this case because **rich:placeHolder** is a new component, but it will not work if we were trying to upgrade a component that exists already.

I think that this same question applies to other frameworks: Primefaces, Icefaces...

What are your suggestions on how to afford this upgrading issues?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

There are three approaches to this kind of an upgrade and it all depends on what most fits the capabilities of your team, budget and time.

### 1) Automated Web Testing

A useful web testing framework like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) can allow you to record web application interaction with your latest stable release, and playback that recorded interaction on a prototyped version of your web application.

The learning curve here is such that a technically skilled QA analyst should be able to walk through an independent recording to verify each documented requirement.

### 2) Modularization Upgrades

The CDK idea sounds like a great risk averse way to slowly upgrade your JSF framework over time.  This is probably the best approach if time and manpower isn't there.

### 3) QA Brute Force

The Quality Assurance team would essentially manually walk through all test cases for all requirements and verify that test cases are still passing.  This is about as labor intensive as the first approach, however the next time a front end library or framework is upgraded then the entire process will have to be repeated.

### The Netscape Method

Netscape was famously known for their downfall during the browser wars in the 90's.  What brought them down was their philosophy on testing and QA.  They believed that users should be the QA, which is a stupid belief because users form 90% of their opinions on a product based on the first impression.

This method basically has the developers brute force upgrade until it compiles, do simple smoke testing, and when everything seems to be okay, release it to production and wait for user feedback to determine bugs.  I don't recommend this approach unless you have a non-critical application and a captive user base.

Comment: **Automated Web Testing** looks to be the most attractive but I think that it is always really hard/expensive to test all the user interface over many pages.